# How decode urt params

Tags: android, kotlin

In my android project I use Retrofit 2

```
@GET("/transfers/tunnels")
    fun getTunnelsList(
        @Query("destination[id]") destinationId: String,
        @Query("amuunt") amount: Double,
        @Query("currency") currency: String
    ): Call<List<Tunnel>>
```

And here result:

```
-> GET http://my_ip/transfers/tunnels?destination%5Bid%5D=9eb5fd41-16f8-430c-91b7-a69ad1fd4c89&amuunt=4.0&currency=EUR http/1.1
```

But I need param with name `destination[id]`

smt like this:

```
-> GET http://my_ip/sends?preferred_agent[id]=12345&amuunt=12.1&currency=USD&receiver[id]=receiverID_guid&destination[id]=destinationId_guid&contract[id]=contractId_guid&is_ready=false
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `encoded` parameter of `Query` annotation to `true`. Then it'll work as intended

```
@GET("/transfers/tunnels")
fun getTunnelsList(
    @Query("destination[id]", encoded = true) destinationId: String,
    @Query("amuunt") amount: Double,
    @Query("currency") currency: String
): Call<List<Tunnel>>
```